# Copy Items from one resource group to another in Azure data lake store using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, command, data-lake

All I want is to copy the data from a development environment to production environment in Azure data lake store. *There is not QA..*

These are .CSV files the **environments** are nothing but different **resource groups.**
I tried copying the data in the similar Resource Group using the command

```
Move-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "xyz" -path "/Product_S
ales_Data.csv" -destination "/mynewdirectory
```

Which worked fine, however, I want the data movement to take place between two different **resource groups**.

*Possible solution* that I have come across is by using the **Export** command which downloads the files in the local machine and then using the **Import** command and uploading them to a different resource group.

```
Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem
Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem
```

The reason behind using a PowerShell is to automate the process of importing the files/copying them across different environment which is nothing but automating the entire deployment process using PowerShell.

The solution mentioned above might help me in taking care of the process but I am looking for a better solution where the local machine or a VM is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a number of options, all of the below will be able to accomplish what you are looking to achieve. Keep in mind that you need to check the limitations of each and weigh the costs. For example, Azure functions have a limited time they can execute (default maximum of 5 minutes) and local storage limitations.

1. [Azure Logic Apps](https://jorgklein.com/2017/08/31/connect-logic-apps-to-data-lake-store-using-a-service-principal/) (drag and from config)
2. [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store) (using the Data Lake lined service)
3. Azure Functions (using the [Data Lake REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/))
4. You could use [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro) and PowerShell to automate your current approach.
5. Use [ADLCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob) to copy between lakes (and other stores)

Choosing which can be opinionated and subjective.

Comment: The list of recommendations you gave was absolutely correct. Data Factory is being used at a later stage when data needs to be cleansed and loaded. The files which I am dealing with right now are raw file and according to the process, they should be manually placed in the Data Lake store so that they are picked up by the further processes I am going to be using Azure automation just need help with the PowerShell **command** where I can move files from one resource group to another.

Comment: Unfortunately, if using PowerShell to go between lakes, you do need to download and upload, you cannot move between lakes.

Comment: Good luck - I believe if you want to avoid having a VM then you will need to use Data Factory, Logic Apps or Functions.